# Não consigo somar retorno jsonArray

Tags: php

Tenho um seguinte problema:

```
function send_notification(){
$jsonArray = json_decode($result);
$cont_sucesso +=  $jsonArray->success;
$cont_falha   +=  $jsonArray->failure;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $num / 1000; $i++) {
 $Status = send_notification();
.....
}
console.log($cont_sucesso); 
echo("Total SUCESSO: ".$cont_sucesso);
echo("</br>");
echo("Total FALHAS: " .$cont_falha);
echo("</br>");
echo "Total de mensagens enviadas: ".$cont;
```

Não consigo somar o valor do `$jsonArray->success;` tenho um loop e dentro desse loop eu chamo função que retorna `jsonArray` 
Mas preciso somar o retorno dele para exibir no final do laço, onde estou errando?

Edit:
Json

```
{"multicast_id":5985558851077455261,"success":254,"failure":746,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1478517570268212%f17b55e1f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

Comment: Posta o json que você está usando

Comment: meu json está certo, pois se eu colocar o echo($jsonArray->success); ele me mostra a quantidade

Comment: A zica está nessas 2 variáveis $cont_sucesso e $cont_falha. To quase jogando na sessão e resgatando depois.

Comment: Esta dando algum erro de PHP ou simplesmente não calcula?

Comment: ele não soma, não da nenhum erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema são os [escopos de váriaveis](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php).

```
function send_notification(){
$jsonArray = json_decode($result);
$cont_sucesso +=  $jsonArray->success; //esta é a variavel dentro do escopo da func send_notification()
$cont_falha   +=  $jsonArray->failure;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $num / 1000; $i++) {
 $Status = send_notification();
.....
}
console.log($cont_sucesso); 
echo("Total SUCESSO: ".$cont_sucesso); //esta é OUTRA variavel no escopo local (fora da send_notification())
echo("</br>");
echo("Total FALHAS: " .$cont_falha);
echo("</br>");
echo "Total de mensagens enviadas: ".$cont;
```

eu fiz um testezinho no http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ com o seguinte código

```
$result = '{"multicast_id":5985558851077455261,"success":254,"failure":746,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1478517570268212%f17b55e1f9fd7ecd"}]}';

function send_notification($result){
    global $cont_sucesso, $cont_falha ; //Agora estou setando as vars do escopo da função como global

    $jsonArray = json_decode($result);
    $cont_sucesso +=  $jsonArray->success;
    $cont_falha   +=  $jsonArray->failure;
}


$cont_sucesso =0;
$cont_falha =0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
 $Status = send_notification($result);
}
echo("Total SUCESSO: ".$cont_sucesso);
echo("</br>");
echo("Total FALHAS: " .$cont_falha);
echo("</br>");
```

Comment: Perfeito!!! Foi só declarar elas como global que deu certo. global $cont_sucesso, $cont_falha ;

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Bartolomeu